# knockout not binding updated data from server

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I am trying to use the ko.mapping plugin to update my viewModel. When the partial view is first opened, I use the following:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = function () {
            return @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
        }();

        model = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(ResultModel(data));
        ko.applyBindings(new model);

    });
```

The data seems to get binded and appears properly in my view. My viewModel is the following:

```
  function Member(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.FirstName = ko.observable(data.FirstName);
        self.LastName = ko.observable(data.LastName);
        self.CountyCollections = ko.observableArray(data.CountyCollections);
        self.CountiesPurchased = ko.observableArray(data.CountiesPurchased);
    }

    var ResultModel = function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Member = new Member(data);

        self.addCounty = function () {            
            var county = {
                countyCode: ko.observable(""),
                countyName: ko.observable(""),
            };
          self.Member.CountyCollections.push(county);
        }.bind(self);

        self.removeCounty = function (county) {
            self.Member.CountyCollections.remove(county);
        }.bind(self);


    };
```

The problem is when I try and update the viewModel with data from the controller using the ko.mapping.fromJS.

```
 $("#SaveReferralsClick").click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/mySurface/Save_Counties",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: ko.toJSON(Member),
            success: function (result) {

             ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, ResultModel.Member);

            }
        });

    });
```

When I examine the data coming back in result (`success: function (result) {`), it appears to be correct and updated. But when I run `ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, ResultModel.Member)`, the viewModel does not get updated.

I have tried multiple variations of calling  `ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, ResultModel.Member)`. For example, when I try
 `ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, ResultModel.Member(result))` I get an error saying Member is not a constructor. It is referring to the following line:

```
 self.Member = new Member(data);
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enbveepv/) with simplified version of your case, it works as expected. Could you update it (with as less code as possible) so it would reproduce your issue?

Comment: Okay, I have updated a [jsfiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/CurtRabon/enbveepv/2/) with a ajax call. I also added a 'load' button that calls ajax to simulate my code. Notice that the first alert shows the correct data coming in, but that the second alert does not show the new data. The main difference I think is that I have ViewModel as a variable instead of a function name.

Comment: I've updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/enbveepv/3/) and added comments. Does it help?

Comment: That works! Thank you. In my javascript file I had the button click function outside of my model. When I moved it inside and reference the self.Member that works. I am guessing that the ko.mapping.fromJS could not map when called outside of the ViewModel.

Comment: Ok, I'll add this as an answer, so you could accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After some clarification in comments it appeared that `ajax` call was made in function that was not part of view model thus causing some context issues. After clarification here how the simplified view model should look like:

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.mappedModel = new Model(data);
    // This method was outside of the model, I moved it here.
    self.load = function() {
        $.ajax({
            ..., // some ajax parameters
            success: function (data) {                
                // map received data to model
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.mappedModel);
            }
        });
    };
};
// Some Model
function Model(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.Collection = ko.observableArray(data.Collection);
}
```

#### [Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/enbveepv/3/)